# googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener() does not work on physical device

Tags: android, google-maps

When I click on InfoWindow of the map marker in emulator it works fine but on the physical device the clicks are not captured. Here is my code.

```
public class FragmentTab1 extends Fragment implements GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener {

private static GoogleMap googleMap = null;

public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);

    googleMap = null;

    db = new DatabaseHelper(MyApplication.getAppContext());
    shopDataArrayList = db.getShops();
    db.closeDB();

    mapMarkerData.clear();
    googleMap = null;

    initilizeMap();
    inflateMapMarker(shopDataArrayList);
    onMapReady();

    return layout;
}

//To initilize googleMap object.
private void initilizeMap() {

    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.home_map)).getMap();
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter());
        googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext(), "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
 //For the first time, this will draw all the points on the map.
public void onMapReady() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mapMarkerData.size() - 1; i++) {
        Log.d("TAG","In onMapReady");
        Marker m = placeMarker(mapMarkerData.get(i));
        marker_data.put(m, mapMarkerData.get(i));
        marker_key.put((i + 1) + "", m);

    }

}

//This is to inflate the mapMarkers with offerData.
private void inflateMapMarker(ArrayList<ShopData> mShopDataArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mShopDataArray.size(); i++) {
        String[] coordinates = mShopDataArray.get(i).getCoordinates().split(",");
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0].substring(1));
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1].substring(0, coordinates[1].length() - 1));
        MapMarkerData lld = new MapMarkerData(lat,lng,mShopDataArray.get(i).getLogo_img(),mShopDataArray.get(i).getShop_name());
        mapMarkerData.add(lld);
        Log.d("TAG",lat+" "+lng);
    }


}

public Marker placeMarker(MapMarkerData mapMarkerData) {

    LatLng location = new LatLng(mapMarkerData.getLat(), mapMarkerData.getLng());

    Marker m = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(Constants.marker_color[1]))
            .title(mapMarkerData.getShop_name())
            .position(location)
            .visible(true));
    return m;

}

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"onInfoWidnow",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    Intent intent = new Intent(FragmentTab1.this.getActivity(), ShopActivity.class);
    //This is to send offerData accross the activites.
    //de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(mofferData.get(position));
    FragmentTab1.this.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    return;

}

private class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    private View view;
    private TextView textView;
    private ImageView imageView;
    public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(){
        view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
        textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.infoWindowText);
        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.infoWindowImg);

    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        final ImageLoader imageLoader = new VolleyHandler().getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(marker_data.get(marker).getLogo_img(), new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Image Load Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) {
                if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                    // load image into imageview
                    Log.d(TAG, "imaged is being loaded");
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                }
            }
        });
        textView.setText(marker_data.get(marker).getShop_name());
        return view;
    }
}
```

Any ideas why it is not working on physical device but on emulator??